# Adding Files to Custom Kali ISO Image

Tags: linux, iso-image, kali-linux, build

I am creating a custom Kali installer image that includes several additional files that I commonly use in every build (rather than adding it after it is installed). Following the Kali documentation (https://www.kali.org/docs/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso/), I add my files to **/kali-config/common/includes.chroot/** directory.  In order to build the ISO, i use the command:

`./build.sh --verbose --variant default --installer`

Once I install the newly configured custom Kali image from the generated ISO file, My added files are nowhere to be found.

How do I build a custom Kali **installer** that includes custom additional files/directories?

Comment: Can you post the build.log and the one of the packages you were attempting to install?

Comment: I wasn't installing a package, i was trying to add files.

Comment: Ok; Then provide the log and at least one of those files.

Comment: the file is inconsequential, nothing that I add in the specified directory seems to show up.  I just tried with a plaintext file with the word "test" in it.  The log file is over 8k lines, rather than just coping the entire thing, is there a specific snippet of it that you want me to include?

Comment: I want to look at the log file, of the the image generation process, to see if the file is even touched.  *Something like Pastebin will be fine build.log`*